# Support for XNA WP7 and flash with existing C++ code base - pipeline, tools and approaches

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, xna, haxe

all.
We are game development company and we develop casual games for PC/MAC/iOS/Android with our own engine written in C++ (90-100%) and we are happy with it!

Now we want to target XNA/WP7 and flash.

What is the best way for doing this ?

Of course we will have to rewrite some low-level stuff like sprite rendering/timing/audio support, but we want to put as less efforts as possible in porting game code itself.

**A. We do not want to rewrite game code two time more**

**B. Ideally even one time more :)**

For flash we are going to use [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) together with [this library](http://code.google.com/p/polygonal/wiki/DataStructures).
It would be awesome to have C# target support in Haxe. It has been announced but never released and I think it will not be released in nearest future. But I think it will be released in 1-2 years. So in porting different engine components to Haxe is potentially great investment.

Until then we have to decide how to meet A and B.

Possible variants for dealing with it:

1. Using [mokey](http://www.monkeycoder.co.nz/). However languaged seems to be so primitive and so different from C++/AS3/C#/etc what we decided not to use it.
2. First of all develop XNA port with the help of brains and [C++ to C# converter](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Products.html). Then use [C# to Haxe converter](http://cs2hx.codeplex.com/). This approach seems to be the best one at this moment, but I have no idea about how much time convertors will save compared to straightforward code rewrite. However, I think they will help.
3. It is also possbile to use [Adobe Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/) for flash support. However we will have to develop new architecture to separate render/audio and logic into different languages and we want to avoid this - it seems to be more complex than code porting.

So what do you think about 1-3 and do you know better options to achieve A and B ?
Maybe other meta languages/approaches/technologies ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is your absolute best/ideal solution:

http://www.mandreel.com/?page_id=48

http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=2593

Basically it's a framework/compiler that will compile c/cpp/objc to iOS, Android, Flash, WP7, and much more.

Comment: It looks absolutely best solution, however we need to try it.

Comment: I guess you'd have to contact them and see what they can do for you. :)

Comment: i wrote them several times and had no answer at all. i asked to call me and asked for their phone to call them but HAD NO ANSWER.